# display only the subdata of the category in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code and i want to only show who are the customer owned the car

```
SELECT a.customername,
       b.carplate
FROM customertld a
LEFT JOIN carstld b ON a.carid=b.carid
WHERE `carid`=1
```

the out put would be like this
honda civic:
thomas
eric
beth
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
   SELECT CONCAT(a.customername,': ', b.carplate) AS CarOwner
     FROM customertld a
LEFT JOIN carstld b ON a.carid=b.carid
    WHERE b.carid=1
```

Comment: tnx thats what i want sorry for bad english